# Bootstrap not responding when I use col-* and take the full width, although it work in large screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I linked Bootstrap 3 as usual, but when I testing page col-md not working in medium screen and it work in large. Where is the problem? And it repeating in all col-md in page, also I noticed that it take if full width of the container

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row wow animated fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="services-item">
                        <div class="services-item-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="services-item-title">
                            <h3>Web Design</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="services-item-text">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br> adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: So, your problem is that on screens of width `992px` or up, the `<div class=col-md-4>` don't get the full widht, but on screens of lower width that div gets full width?. If you expect to have `4 `of the `12` available columns on small screens, thne you have to use `col-xs-4 `, not `col-md-4`. The definition for `col-md-4` is to take 4 of 12 columns for medium or larger screens (width >= 992px) and to take 12 of 12 columns for small or extra small screens (width < 992px).

Comment: the problem in screen with max-width: 992px, but as i understand col-md (max-width≥992px)an (min-width 768px) from this docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container

Comment: When you use `col-md-n` with `1 <= n <= 12` **n** will be the number of columns to use (of 12 available) for screen sizes equal or larger than **md**. For screen sizes lower than **md** 12 columns are taken by default unless you specify other thing. Example: `<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">` will use 8 columns for **XS** and **SM** screens and 4 columns for **MD**, **LG** and **XL**. Hope you understand, anyway, if you clarify what is your real problem I will help with a solution.

Comment: Ok i understand and thank you so much i just have simple question i clearly understand your idea for medium and large devices but how can i make     
col-md-6  in screen  over than 480px and col-md-12 down that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work I believe you are looking for the following. Giving it full width on xs devices and half width on sm devices and 1/3 width on med and up. Please read documentation of bootstrap grid system here. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="services-item">
         <div class="services-item-icon">
              <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-3x"></i>
         </div>
         ....
    </div>
</div>
```